# child ul dropdown is cut off because of it's parent height

Tags: html, css

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
   ...
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have 4 elments in div tag but only 2 are shown. How can I increase it's height show all dropdown items.

I have used overflow:auto; but this is adding scroll to entire parent element which is not looking good. Also padding-bottom also works here but it extends parent's background behind the dropdwn which is not needed.

```
fuelux .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 23%;
  min-width: 50px;
  display: block;
```

}

```
 .fuelux .carousel-inner {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   line-height: 1;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same problem until few minutes ago and below is what solved my issue.

> style="min-height:300px;max-height:100%;"

---

You need to set the min-height of parent div to expanded child menu height size so that the child menu will be displayed with out cutting off by the parent height.

We are setting max-height so that CSS won't consider min-height as the default fixed height of the component. so that it will expand if you are using any Dynamic loading content like GroupBoxes, Choosen boxes with long list, etc.,.

```
   <div class="carousel-inner" style="min-height:300px;max-height:100%;">
   ...
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Note : For the Menu i am loading 300px is the maximum height required to load complete child menu. Check your height of expanded menu size and change it with min-height value to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the height to the div-wrapper?

If yes, drop the height out of the stylesheet and the height is automatically set by the content inside the div-wrapper.

For example:

Style:

```
div {
width: 200px; float: left;
}

ul li {
height: 20px; width: 200px; float: left;
}
```

when you have 4 elements inside ul, the height of die div-wrapper will be 80px.

I hope i can help you ;)

Comment: I am using min-height to the wrapper class... so it's increasing as per the contents but doesn't change for this dropdown.

Comment: why you are using `overflow: hidden;` in the .carousel-inner ? The height of .carousel-inner should increase automatically?

Comment: yes.. I also checked that... if I change it to auto or scroll then I could see the dropdown but scrollbar is shown for the parent element which is not looking gud.. so is there any other option to implement that without scrollbar??